# How to make all my activities listen to device's shakes?

Tags: android, listener, sensors, android-sensors

How to make application listen to device's shakes? I mean not the only activity in the app, but all of them.I used TabActivity and did all the logic of registering/unregistering SensorManager here and also implemented it as SensorEventListener to detect shakes. Then activities in tabs listened for custom OnShakeListener, declared in my TabActivity. but this logic lead to crash. Was I right choosing this way of implementation and should look for mistakes? OR Should I use a Service instead to get what I want? Or is there any other way?

Comment: If you are doing something specific to each activity with that data then it doesn't make sense to me to use a common listener. If you are just wanting to log that data or something no matter what activity you are on, then a service might make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Implement shake listener (`SensorEventListener`) in one `abstract` `Activity` (say: `ShakeListenerActivity`) and get all other `Activity` extending you `ShakeListenerActivity`.

define an abstract method (say: `shakeDetected(Params...)`) in `ShakeListenerActivity` and override it in all child `Activities`.

In child `Activity`'s `shakeDetected(Params...)` you can implement different logic accordingly.

call `shakeDetected()` whenever you detect any shake through `SensorEventListener`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this way with no success.May be I was wrong with choosing the place to register/unregister SensorManager... Where should I do it using this way? in TabActivity or any else?

Comment: register it in `onCreate()` and unregister it in `onDestroy()` of `ShakeListenerActivity`